# Would you expect different outputs from these two command chains?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm working on a project for a Linux class, we're writing a script to pull stats from a log file. This specific command chain is to get the number of users running MSIE 6.0. I'm wondering why I'm getting different results between these.

```
# following the professor's steps 
cut -f6 $log \
    | grep -v 'MSIE 8.0' \
    | grep -v 'MSIE 7.0' \
    | grep 'MSIE 6.0'    \
    | cut -d ';' -f2     \
    | uniq -c
# returns 169253`
```

```
# using grep -o seems like a more efficient solution to me?
cut -f6 $log \
    | grep -v 'MSIE 8.0' \
    | grep -v 'MSIE 7.0' \
    | grep -o 'MSIE 6.0' \
    | uniq -c
# returns 169760
```

If I use `grep -o` to get stats about any other browser I get an exact match for the number of entries with that particular browser. I'm just curious why these are different.

Comment: Without seeing your input data, we can't be sure...  Of particular interest are lines containing `MSIE 6.0`... and the text that is after the semicolon. The first will only consider uniqie text after, while the first will just count all lines that contain `MSIE 6.0`.

Comment: You could stick both results (with `uniq` instead of `uniq -c`) in your favorite diff tool and take a look.

Comment: The first snippet returns `169253` for `MSIE 6.0` *and* something more in other lines, right? The second snippet returns `169760` for `MSIE 6.0` and nothing more, right. Have you considered `MSIE 6.0` may be somewhere else than in the second field? Have you tested what happens when there are two `MSIE 6.0` strings in a single line?

Comment: @Attie thanks for the edit to my post, made it much more readable.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think you're right, from my understanding of the logs I'm inputting it could be possible that `MSIE 6.0` is in another field, just not something I had thought of. Thanks for your input!

Comment: From the context of learning what's going on, remember that there's nothing wrong with truncating the pipeline step by step and simply looking at the output produced. (Also, notice that the first two `grep` commands are probably irrelevant - your three `grep` commands together say _skip MSIE 8_ and then _skip MSIE 7_ and then _only include MSIE 6_; logically this is the same as just _only include MSIE 6_.)

Answer (score 1):

#### The 2 commands are not synonymous.

The first command reduced the amount of data available to be compared by removing the first part of the input. **This has obviously had the net effect of making more lines in the output identical.** Because the lines are identical they are only counted once.

I posit that if you replaced `uniq -c` with `wc -l` the number of lines would increase but would match in both cases.